# How to set product description in Paypal request

Tags: php, magento, paypal

My client got papal Payment notification email without any product description.The portion for product description in email was getting blank.When I contact Paypal they said that " PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESC " field was blank on the request.

how to set this through Magento Code ? Could i set a common description for all payment ?

Comment: This might be better asked on the Magento StackExchange

Comment: The simple answer is that you need to adjust the SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment requests that Magento is sending to PayPal.  That won't exactly be easy, though, if you're not familiar with building Magento extensions.  You could just hack the core code to add that parameter, but that's not recommended.

Comment: Do you know the path of core file that send these requests ?